# Compile cells when cell contains certain value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, I have a range of values as follows:

[image]

I am looking for a formula that will search the range, find all of the cells that is a 'wire' (contains the term "wire") and outputs the range to a compiled list of all of the wires in the A column list like this:

[image]

I could tell you what I've tried, but I haven't even gotten close, so I feel it's irrelevant.

Here is a copy of the example spreadsheet for copy-paste if needed: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QDvAo5epuwBEzeOPrBckb1GO6wKOA6q6K83C1-SeQGA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A:A; "where A contains 'Wire'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Boom!  That's it.  I figured it would be something in Query.  That's something I have yet to educate myself on.  Thanks so much for the help!